# Problem with error SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-3, java-11

Hello I've got a problem with simple code. I wanted to try to use slf4j with this code

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);
    logger.info("Hello World!");
}
```

but I have an error

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Can you help me?

Comment: What dependencies do you have in your project? Please share pom.xml.

Comment: <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `<scope>test</scope>` from the `slf4j-simple` dependency and refresh the Maven project in the IDE. With the `test` scope the dependency will be available only for the code in `src/test/java` and not available for the main app production code in `src/main/java`.

[image: Proof]

Comment: @Draxa you need to [reload the project](https://i.imgur.com/C6GKLVS.png) after removing the `<scope>test</scope>` line. If it doesn't help, please zip and share your project directory.

Comment: Nothing changed. My code https://www.easypaste.org/file/DUiRZTsP/mavenstart.zip?lang=pl

Comment: @Draxa your project [runs without errors](https://i.imgur.com/Jg9AfHg.png). Try to delete .idea directory and import the pom.xml file again. If it doesn't help, post the full command line in the run console output.